# How to set path to files in Apache Spark Standalone Cluster?

Tags: apache-spark

I need some hints about defining a path to a directory with lots of files in Spark. I have set up a Standalone Cluster with one machine as Worker and another machine as Master and the driver is my local machine. I develop my code on the local machine with python. I have copied all files to the Master and Worker, the path on both machines is equal (like: /data/test/). I have set up a SparkSession but now I do not know how to define the path to the directory in my script. So my problem is how to say Spark that it can find the data on both machines in the directory above? 
Another question for me is how to deal with file formats like .mal, how can I read in such files? Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a spark job is submitted to a driver (master), few things happended

1. Driver program creates an execution plan. It creates multiples stages and each stage contains multiple tasks.
2. Cluster manager allocate resources and launch executors from worker based on arguments whiling submitting the job.
3. The tasks are given to executors to be executed and driver monitor each task execution. Resources is deallocated and executors are terminated when `sparkContext` is closed or the scope of application program is finished.

The driver or master where spark job is submitted needs the accessible data path, as it control all the execution plan. Driver program and cluster manager will take care all the things to do different kinds of operation in the worker. As the spark job is submitted in master,  It's enough to provide the data path which is accessible by spark from the master machine.